# working with function preg_replace_callback in a row several times?

Tags: php, preg-replace-callback

I try to label the preg_replace_callback function differently in one line

```php
$textline = "[italic] Hello *Bold*!\n";
$textline .= "[true] Yes *Haaa*, you are *super*\n";
function italic($treffer) { 
 return '<i>'.$treffer[1].'</i>';
}
function bold($treffer) {
 return '<b>'.$treffer[1].'</b>';
}
echo preg_replace_callback('#\[(.*?)\]#', ('italic'.'bold'), $text);
//echo preg_replace_callback('#\*(.*?)\*#', 'italic', $text);
//echo preg_replace_callback('#\*(.*?)\*#', 'bold', $text);
```

result:

> Warning: preg_replace_callback(): Requires argument 2,...

expect:

```html
<i>italic</i> Hello <b>Bold</b>!
<i>true</i> Yes <b>Haaa</b>, you are <b>super</b>!
```

Comment: `'italic'.'bold'` is equivalent to `italicbold`, there is no such function.

Comment: Additionally, please share the **full** error message for your next question

Answer (score 0):

There's no need for `preg_replace_callback` here, just use an array of regular expressions and replacements with `preg_replace`

```
echo preg_replace(['/\[(.*?)\]/', '/\*(.*?)\*/'], ['<i>$1</i>', '<b>$1</b>'], $text);
```

If you do want to use `preg_replace_callback()` you can capture the delimiter and use an `if` statement:

```
echo preg_replace_callback('/([[*])(.*?)[]*]/', function($matches) {
    if ($matches[1] == '[') {
        return italic($matches[2]);
    } elseif ($matches[1] == '*') {
        return bold($matches[2]);
    }
}, $text);
```